# Delete space and replace non-ASCII characters in filenames via a loop with a makefile

Tags: regex, makefile, filenames

In a folder full of image files I would like to delete any spaces in the file name. Furthermore I want that non-ASCII characters are replaced by a dash `-`.
This needs to be done via a makefile.

Note: The final dot before the suffix/extension of the file has to remain.

example:

"Fig. 3_16mm_300dpi_1to1_obv.tif" --> "Fig-3-16mm-300dpi-1to1-obv.tif"

My approach so far

```
IMGPATH  = "workfiles/inserts/figures"

cleanfigures:
    cd $(IMGPATH) && \
        for f in *; \
        do \
        mv -v "$$f" "$${f//[^a-zA-Z0-9](?=.*?\.)/-}" ; \
        done
```

The regex command (`[^a-zA-Z0-9](?=.*?\.)`) is fine when I test it with https://regex101.com/ but it will not work accordingly with the makefile, since nothing is renamed or replaced.

Comment: What do you mean by _not work_? Errors? Wrong results? Besides, in order to see if the regex works, why not putting the whole `for` loop in a script to which you pass only `$$f`?

Comment: *not work* = nothing changes in the filename. Can you provide an example with the script?

Comment: Actually I do not want to have another file/script

Comment: (1) Based on the link you attached, the regex flavor you are trying to use is JS or PHP, not one you can use in `bash`. (2) You refer to non-ASCII characters, but then you just try to substitute characters which are not letters or numbers, while ASCII is more than that. (3) What is that look ahead for? It is looking for a litteral `.`. Why?

Comment: ok - so I have to look for a regex pattern that would work with bash....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you wanted to change all non-ASCII characters to `-`. However based on your attempt, it seems you only want to transform to `-` those characters which are not digits or "plain" letters (by plain I mean non accented, non fancy, ...).

```
cleanfigures:
    for f in *; \
    do \
    ext="$${f##*.}" ; \
    base="$${f%.*}" ; \
    newbase="$${base//[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/-}" ; \
    echo "$$f" "$${newbase// /}.$$ext" ; \
    done
```

Comment: this works but it will replace the dot before the suffix, too. This shouldnt be done.

Comment: Oh, you could add that requirement in the question.

Comment: sorry, just did.